# Animation border

Tags: wpf, xaml, eventtrigger

I have border, that I want to animate by clicking button (name = "button1"). Button is outside. My code throws an exception. Whats wrong? Thanks

```
  <Border Name="brdClasses" Background="#FF2c3e50">
                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="MyAnimatedScaleTransform" 
                                         ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"  />
                    </Border.RenderTransform>
                    <Border.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger SourceName="button1" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Name="MyBeginStoryboard">
                                    <Storyboard >
                                        <DoubleAnimation 
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="MyAnimatedScaleTransform"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                To="3.0" Duration="0:0:10" AutoReverse="True" />

                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger.Actions>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Border.Triggers>
                </Border>
```

Comment: `My code throws an exception.` is too broad. Be more specific.

Comment: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
More information: "Initialization" System.Windows.Controls.Border "caused an exception." Row number "51" and the position in the string "27". it underlines </EventTrigger>

Answer (score 0):

I Dont know why your code doent works... But I did a simple example in a specific way.. if it helps make use of that..

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Name="brdClasses" Grid.Row="1" Background="#FF2c3e50" Height="100" Width="150">
       <Border.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Border.RenderTransform>
    </Border>
    <Button Content="Button1" x:Name="button1">
        <Button.Triggers>
           <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="button1">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="brdClasses">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="3"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```